# Can I disable input filters in a view?

Tags: views

I have created an admin-only view on a certain content type where we want to review the body content all in one place. The problem is that the input format for these nodes does some additional glossary markup etc. and we want to see the raw body content.

Is there a way to disable or change the input format for this view without changing it for each node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope i understand the question correctly:

In views you can check the option "**Strip html tags**" in options.

[image]

Comment: That's a good idea - basically letter the input filters run as normal, but then strip out any tags they insert afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

I dont' think this is possible via the UI.  You could use tokens and a PHP field or some custom theming to do it.

I would probably do custom theming or a preprocess function although I understand those are somewhat advanced topics.

This might be a helpful resource for you:
http://evolvingweb.ca/story/theming-views-drupal-templates-and-preprocess-functions